# How to run several instances on the same server?

Tags: node.js, express, proxy, sails.js

I'd like to run two instances of a Sails.js API on the same server. I've only got one domain name and would like something like:

- v1.0 running on https://api.example.com/1.0/
- v1.1 running on https://api.example.com/1.1/

How is it possible with Sails/Express/Node.js? Is there any module to handle that kind of problem? Or do I need a proxy server like Apache or Nginx?

Comment: I think you need a proxy server. Nginx (location) for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do with [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy)

You have sails server 1 in port 8080 for example and sails server 2 to port 8081.
And now with http-proxy on port 80 you can redirect /1.0/ to server 1 and v1.1 to server 2.

Here is an example of http-proxy you can use (not tested) :

```
var http = require('http'), httpProxy = require('http-proxy'), proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({}), url = require('url');

proxy.on("error", function(err){console.log(err);});//Prevent proxy crash by socket hang out error

var proxyServer = http.createServer(function (req, res)
{
    var hostname = req.headers.host.split(":")[0]; 

    switch (hostname+req.url)
    {
        case 'api.example.com/1.0':
            proxy.web(req, res, {target : 'http://localhost:8080'});
            break;
        case 'api.example.com/1.1':
            proxy.web(req, res, {target : 'http://localhost:8081'});
            break;
        default:
            proxy.web(req, res, {target : 'http://localhost:8080'});
    }
});

//
// Listen to the `upgrade` event and proxy the
// WebSocket requests as well.
//
proxyServer.on('upgrade', function (req, socket, head)
{
    var hostname = req.headers.host.split(":")[0]; 

    switch (hostname+req.url)
    {
        case 'api.example.com/1.0':
            proxy.ws(req, socket, {target : 'ws://localhost:8080'});
            break;
        case 'api.example.com/1.1':
            proxy.ws(req, socket, {target : 'ws://localhost:8081'});
            break;
        default:
            proxy.ws(req, socket, {target : 'ws://localhost:8080'});
    }
});
proxyServer.listen(80, function ()
{
    console.log('proxy listening on port 80');
});
```

You can do the same with Apache or Nginx but you ask for full node solution :)

Comment: Is there a way to block direct requests to :8080/:8081?

Comment: You can make a sails policy in your 2 servers that check the hostname and allow only localhost then a forbidden page. I don't know how do this another way...